# Sequential model always predicts 5

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras, neural-network

So I've got a sequential model from mostly following along with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ8BIBpya2k) video. I've also got a drawing app done in JS and am sending the contents of that canvas to a flask server using JQuery.  All of that seems to be working fine but when I give my model the image from the canvas and call predict it always gives me back the same exact response. The values at each index are always the same.

Am I missing something simple? Am I calling the predict wrong in the server or is it something to do with the model itself? It gets the predictions correct in the notebook.

Thanks for your time!

**Flask server:**

```
model = load_model('MyModel.h5')
imageWidth = 28
imageHeight = 28
dim = (imageWidth, imageHeight)

#   Create the flask web application
app = fl.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/uploadimage', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def uploadimage():
    #   Get the image from the request
    theImage = fl.request.values.get("theImage", "")

    #Decode the string to an image
    decodedimg = base64.b64decode(theImage[22:])

    #   Save the image
    with open ("theImage.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(decodedimg)

    #   Open the image from the request as originalImage
    originalImage = Image.open("theImage.png")

    #   Resize it
    resizedImage = ImageOps.fit(originalImage, dim, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    #   Confirm the dimensions of the resized image
    w1, h1 = resizedImage.size
    print(w1, h1)

    #   Save it locally
    resizedImage.save("resizedImage.png", quality=100, optimize=True)

    #   Convert to grayscale and then convert that to an array
    grayscaleImage = ImageOps.grayscale(resizedImage)
    grayscaleArray = np.array(grayscaleImage)
    grayscaleArray.shape    #   Gives (20, 20)

    grayscaleArray = grayscaleArray.reshape(1, 28, 28)

    setPrediction = model.predict(grayscaleArray)
    print(setPrediction)    #   Always gives back same values
    getPrediction = np.array(setPrediction[0])

    predictedNumber = str(np.argmax(getPrediction))
    print(predictedNumber)  #   Always '5'

    return predictedNumber
```

**Model:**

```
model = kr.models.Sequential() # Create a new sequential neural network
model.add(kr.layers.Flatten()) # Input layer
model.add(kr.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")) # 128 neurons and the 'basic' activation function.
model.add(kr.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(kr.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"]) # Played around with 'sgd' and 'rmsporp' optimizer also.

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3)

val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print(val_loss, val_acc)
```

Comment: Why don't you check what your samples look like to make sure you are creating your samples properly (training and one's you are making for prediction). NN's will by default just guess the average of the training outputs, maybe it's possible that is what's happening? Also is there a reason why you're using sparse cat crossent instead of non-sparse?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Yeah I've checked the training and test data to verify it's correct I just figured the only relevant piece I'd need to get help would be the actual model. Also I'm using sparse because that's the way it was done in the video! Having played around with other losses none of them let the model compile and give an error saying the dense layer was expected to have a shape 10 but gt an array with shape 1!

Comment: Based on your model i can't see why you couldn't use 'categorical_crossentropy'. Later i can try to run the code myself. Either way, one reason this could be happening is that there is simply no correlation between your inputs and outputs. What are your inputs and outputs? Also i'm not too familiar with image tasks but i would make sure you are creating your pixel array and scaling your pixels correctly... https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-manually-scale-image-pixel-data-for-deep-learning/

Comment: Tried it again just to make sure and still getting the same error. The input is a 28x28 png image. But I change that to a greyscaled array to call the predict on it. I tried calling .flatten on the array but then the model says it is expecting a 3 dimensional array. Would I be better off trying it without the flatten layer in the model?

Comment: I see that here ImageOps.grayscale(resizedImage) you are converting your image to grayscale. I'll assume that you have viewed the image beforehand and it is valid. Afterwards you are reshaping from (20, 20) to (1, 28, 28), what is your reasoning for this? And i don't see anywhere where you are scaling your data?

Comment: Yeah it’s a valid image beforehand. I can view it in vs code! I’m reshaping it because the model expects a 3 dimensional array! The comment that said it’s 20x20 is outdated and I need to get rid of it. It’s actually 28x28! I appreciate your time btw!

Comment: Would messaging you the github repository help?